# ScalaTest: merge multiple html outputs (-h option)

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I use ScalaTest 3.0.0 in a multi-project build and use `-h directory` to use the html reporter to generate a nice html report. Is it possible to merge the test results of multiple projects into one such html report? Currently, there's one such report generated for every subproject.

Comment: seems to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961332/can-scalatest-generate-a-single-html-report-for-all-subprojects

Comment: maybe even a duplicate?